# Is it possible to define how an object will behave under destructuring assignment in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know that I can do some funky things with javascript objects, such as defining how they behave under `+` by implementing `valueOf`.

Is it possible to do something similar with destructuring assignment? For example, if I define a custom object that behaves somewhat like an Array (say, a range or a Maybe type), I would like to do this:

```js
const [first, ...rest] = myRange
```

Comment: You can make it iterable, but `rest` will always be an array.

Comment: Can you an example of `myRange` object?

Comment: @Ry do you mean to say that destructuring assignment works on any iterables? If my range object implements iterable, then I can use it on the right hand side of a destructuring assignment? (I'm OK with ...rest being an array).

Comment: Yes, destructuring assignment works on any iterable. Yes, if your range object implements iterable, you can use it on the right hand side of a destructuring assignment. (Yes, you can just try this. ;P

Comment: @Ziggy almost: **array destructuring** works on iterables like for example: `const [first, ...rest] = "lorem ipsum";` **object destructuring** works on anything that has *(may have)* keys; so everything except of `null` and `undefined`. `const {0: first, length, ...rest} = "lorem ipsum";` Where `{...rest}` captures the remaining *own enumerable* keys.